# How to get CPU usage statistics for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to get CPU usage details for Windows Phone. 
I have tried DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue() from [MSDN(DeviceExtendedProperties)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But that only gives more of device memory related stuff. 
So, is there any class that exposes CPU related internals for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2):

With WP7x I am sure nothing like that is exposed. Not 100% with WP8 but I doubt they have exposed such low level functionality

Comment: +1. Confirming that the WP8 SDK doesn't expose CPU statistics APIs. However, It is exposed via WP8 Profiling from VS2012.